# Cell reference out of range on Google Spreedsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to do a script to iterate over a column in a sheet, compare the cell value with another cells and changing the background color when they are equal.

I am new both to JS and google scripting, so I am having problems with a for loop, as I always get a "Cell reference out of range" error. Here is my code so far:

```
function onOpen()
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Exibicao");

  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();

  for(var i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
  {
    var cell = range.getCell(i, 13);

    var option1 = cell.offset(0, -3);
    var option2 = cell.offset(0, -2);
    var option3 = cell.offset(0, -1);

    if(option1.getValue() == cell.getValue()){
      option1.setBackground("#b6d7a8");
    }else if(option2.getValue() == cell.getValue()){
      option2.setBackground("#b6d7a8");
    }else if(option3.getValue() == cell.getValue()){
      option3.setBackground("#b6d7a8");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which line is the error thrown on? Logging the cell location after each line may give you a better idea of where it's going out of bounds.

```
var cell = range.getCell(i, 13);
Logger.log( cell.getA1Notation() );

var option1 = cell.offset(0, -3);
Logger.log( option1.getA1Notation() );
```

On second look, think you'll need some thing like this...

```
function onOpen()
{  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Exibicao");

  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();

  // Get values all at once
  var values = range.getValues();
  var row, len, bgs = [], rowBg = [];

  for(row = 0, len = values.length; row < len; row++) {
    var cell = values[row][12];
    var option1 = values[row][9];
    var option2 = values[row][10];
    var option3 = values[row][11];

    rowBg = ['white', 'white', 'white'];
    if( option1 == cell ){
      rowBg[0] = "#b6d7a8";
    }else if( option2 == cell ){
      rowBg[1] = "#b6d7a8";
    }else if( option3 == cell ){
      rowBg[2] = "#b6d7a8";
    }

    bgs.push(rowBg);
  }
  //Logger.log(bgs)
  // Set background colors all at once, start at the top left
  sheet.getRange(1, 10).offset(0, 0, bgs.length, bgs[0].length).setBackgrounds(bgs);
}
```

Comment: Well, in the context of `getCell()`, the arguments are one-based, which I think is where the error is arising. So perhaps should use `for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++)`. Although (as I'm sure Bryan would agree), in the bigger picture, performing all these gets inside a loop is not really the right way of going about it.

Comment: Sorry, the error was on `var cell = range.getCell(i, 13);`

But I did as AdamL told, changing the for to `i = 1` and it worked, thank you. As for the gets inside the loop, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, added in a suggestion. See if it makes sense. Certainly more efficient that way as Adam eluded to. You know the new built-in conditional formatting in Sheets can do this now, right?

Comment: I know, but it was for an old sheet, so I had to do it by script

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I would bet that the issue is in the declaration of your loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= rows; i++)
```

JavaScript arrays are [0-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), which means that an array with a length of `2` has its first element at `arrayName[0]` and its last element at `arrayName[length - 1]`.

Your loop starts with `i = 0`, and ends with `i = range.getNumRows()`. This means that the array starts at the `first` element and ends with trying to get one more row than is in the array. It ends with `arrayName[length]` instead of `arrayName[length - 1]`.

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
```

And if that doesn't work, try this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
```

Both of these access `getNumRows()` elements, not `getNumRows() + 1` elements.

Good luck!